# Standard limit proof

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Everyone knows the standard result $$\boxed{\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x=e}$$ My friend gave a proof for this result using binomial expansion of $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^n=1+nx+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\dots$$ which is valid only when $|1/x|<1$ and $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Here is how he proceeded-
$$\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+x.\dfrac1x+\dfrac{x(x-1)}{2!}\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}\dfrac1{x^3}+\dots\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+1+\dfrac{x(x-1)}{2!}\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}\dfrac1{x^3}+\dots\right)=1+1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x(x-1)}{2!}\dfrac1{x^2}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}\dfrac1{x^3}+\dots=1+1+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}\dots=\boxed{e}\end{align*}$$ The method of binomial expansion is clearly invalid as the exponent $x$ is variable not a constant. Yet the method ends up getting correct answer as $e$. Am I missing what is incorrect here? I am interested to know why this wrong approach leads to correct answer.

Comment: Possibly helpful: look at the Taylor series expansion for `x^r` where `r` is irrational and note that it loosely looks similar to the result when `r` is a natural number, at least for the first few terms.

Comment: @barrycarter Indeed. But still it does not answer why the wrong approach leads to correct answer $e$

Comment: `16/64 = 1/4` by cancelling the sixes :) ... there are plenty of cases where the wrong method can still somehow yield the right answer

Comment: Interesting question. I doubt it's as simple as your friend probably thinks it is...

Comment: @AdamRubinson Exactly. The binomial approach is wrong as the exponent $x\to\infty$ and not a constant value. Is my point correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct for each $\vert x \vert > 1$:

$$ \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^ x =
1+1+\dfrac{x(x-1)}{2!}\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}\dfrac1{x^3}+\dots$$

It is simply [Newton's Generalised Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) with $x$ replaced by $1$, $y$ replaced by $\frac{1}{x}$ and $r$ replaced by $x.$

However, It is not obvious that the following *limit* even converges (although it probably does for some complicated reason):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+x\cdot\dfrac1x+\dfrac{x(x-1)}{2!}\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}\dfrac1{x^3}+\dots\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Instead of taking a limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$, one can take a limit along a specific sequence. For instance, the following limit does not exist:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sin x.$$
Sine is periodic and does not converge to a specific value for large $x$. However, the following limit does exist:
$$\lim_{x=0,\pi,2\pi,\ldots} \sin x = 0.$$
Here we are taking a limit along a countable sequence, skipping over the peaks and troughs of $\sin x$ so that the sine of of every value in the sequence is 0.

Your friend is taking the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ along a particular sequence which grows to infinity, specifically, $x=1,2,3,\ldots$. This is a perfectly valid thing to do, and his math seems correct. Of course, in his case the limit exists not just along this sequence, but as $x \rightarrow \infty$ in general. When the general limit exists, it must equal the limit along every single sequence which grows to infinity, which is what you are seeing here.

Comment: I got your excellent answer. But still I have something to ask. This method to evaluate the limit is not correct always, isn't it? For example, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}+\dfrac{n}{n^2+2}+\dfrac{n}{n^2+3}+\dots+\dfrac{n}{n^2+5n}\right)=5$$ However, if we separate the limit into the sum of individual limits, the answer turns out to be $0$. So it is a mere coincidence that the answer by wrong approach turns out be correct?

Comment: In my opinion this is an incorrect answer. His friend is clearly taking the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty,$ not just along the particular sequence $x=1,2,3,\ldots$. What makes you think the limit is being taken along that sequence only?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I didn't mean to suggest that the friend knew what he was doing and was only interested in the limit along the sequence. I imagine that he took the limit only along the sequence by accident, but he did so correctly.

Comment: But the method of "calculating the limit of a subsequence" sometimes fails to give the limit of the original sequence, which may not exist. For example, $\sin(\pi), \sin(2\pi), \sin(3\pi), \sin(4\pi), \ldots\ $ has limit $0,\ $ but $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x)\ $ does not exist. You cannot use convergence of a specific subsequence as evidence that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ converges [unless you have *also* proved also that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ converges, then yes any subsequence will *tell you what the limit is...*.]

Comment: And this is relevant because with the OP's question, it isn't obvious at all if the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+x\cdot\dfrac1x+\dfrac{x(x-1)}{2!}\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}\dfrac1{x^3}+\dots\right)$ *converges*.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @AdamRubinson. To your point: yes, exactly. I'm saying that the friend mistakenly took a limit sequence along a sequence (but did so correctly) when he should have taken a limit of a continuous function.